# Pass value from Statefulwidget to Providerclass Flutter

Tags: flutter, oop, flutter-dependencies, provider

i want to pass postid value from a statefulwidget to a function inside Providerclass, somebody please help

```
class CommentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postid;
  final String postdescription;
  CommentPage({
    required this.postdescription,
    Key? key,
    required this.postid,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<CommentPage> createState() => _CommentPageState();
}
```

Providerclass

```
class CommentPageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static CommentPageProvider instance = CommentPageProvider();

  List<HomeFeedDataModel> homeFeedDatacollection = [];
  List<CommentsModelData> commentsDatacollection = [];
  List<SingleUserPostModelData> singleuserdatacollection = [];
  bool isLoadingdata = false;
  bool isSingleUserdata = false;

  bool isLikePressed = false;
  bool isLoadCommentsPressed = false;
  bool isLikeButtonPressed = false;
  bool isCommentsDataloaded = false;


 getCommentsData() async {
    isCommentsDataloaded = true;

   commentsData = await CommentService().getCommentsdata(post_id: );

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

so that i can fetch matching comments,

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with passing the post ID into the `getCommentsData()` as a parameter?

```
class CommentPageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static CommentPageProvider instance = CommentPageProvider();

  List<HomeFeedDataModel> homeFeedDatacollection = [];
  List<CommentsModelData> commentsDatacollection = [];
  List<SingleUserPostModelData> singleuserdatacollection = [];
  bool isLoadingdata = false;
  bool isSingleUserdata = false;

  bool isLikePressed = false;
  bool isLoadCommentsPressed = false;
  bool isLikeButtonPressed = false;
  bool isCommentsDataloaded = false;


 getCommentsData(String postId) async {
    // I changed the name of this because there is no 'commentsData' field in your provider class
    commentsDatacollection = await CommentService().getCommentsdata(post_id: postId);
    isCommentsDataloaded = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

By declaring your data collection as nullable (`List<CommentsModelData> commentsDatacollection = [];`), I think you could remove the boolean `isCommentsDataloaded` and simply check for a null value in your widget build method.

### CommentPage

Here you just access the provider and pass through the post ID.

```
class CommentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postid;
  final String postdescription;
  CommentPage({
    required this.postdescription,
    Key? key,
    required this.postid,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<CommentPage> createState() => _CommentPageState();
}

class _CommentPageState extends State<CommentPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<CommentPageProvider>(context).getCommentsData(widget.postId);
  }

}
```

Let me know if this helped!